# call non static method from other class - JavaFX

Tags: static, javafx, java-8, fxml

I have two forms, two separate stages.
The first one contains a method to refresh tableview, it can´t be static.
The second form contains a button which should call a method to refresh the  tableview of the first stage.

How can I do without static function? In java 1.8 We can´t use static for FXML objects. :-/

This is in first class which represent first root form:

```
  public  void seznamDokumentu() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {
        int pocetPriloh = 0;
        System.out.println("start seznam dokumentu!");

        idSoucinnosti.setVisible(nastaveniZobrazTlacitkoSoucinnosti);
        idTable.setEditable(true);
        idTable.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: #" + nastaveniBarvaVybrany
                + "; -fx-accent: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -40%)"
                + "; -fx-cell-hover-color: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -20%)"
//and other actions for refreshing
        );}
```

This is in second class

```
    private static void aktualizuj() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {
//something for call seznamDokumentu()
    }
```

Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get the controller of the FXML. Just load the Fxml in 2 Steps.
First you get just the loader. The loader can load the FXML and give you the controller of it. With that you can call all the public methods from your FXML controller.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("Example.fxml"));
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
YourController controller = loader.getController();
controller.yourRefreshMethod();
```

Comment: I´m lost :D
Controller have to paste in inicialize first class?

Comment: For example there are 2 FXMLs. The Main and the one inside or a neighbour. Then just do some setter Methods and pass the Controller to the other one.
mainController.setControllerOfSecondFXML();
secondController.setControllerOfMaiNFXML();
That way you can call methods from the Controllers to each other

Comment: I deleted line Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();


Now my code looks this :
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("ui/NoveDokumentyView.fxml"));
NoveDokumentyViewController controller = loader.getController();
controller.seznamDokumentu();

This is absolutely what I need :). Thank you

Comment: You're welcome ;) don't forget to mark the answer so the others can see the solution on top too :)

Comment: But not still working 100% :D I see the method I want but I can´t set Parent root in second class.
First class:
 public  void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("ui/NoveDokumentyView.fxml"));
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
 loader.setController(root);
 Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        
    stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("SYSSEL MANAGER");
        stage.show();}

Comment: second class:

 public  void aktualizuj() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {

 public  void aktualizuj() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {
//something for call seznamDokumentu()

//FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(this.getClass().getResource("ui/NoveDokumentyView.fxml"));
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
NoveDokumentyViewController controller = loader.getController();
controller.seznamDokumentu();

  

    }

Comment: Controller should be a Controller and not a Parent Node :P and for what reason do you need the root node in the class itself? If you want to update something work with events. At the time when the Window should change fire and Event. With that event you trigger the update

Comment: So what I can do?
in second class shouldn´t be definition of root node?

Comment: The question is - what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: I try solve situation in this example
http://www.codeshare.io/B9U4B
I don´t understand so much things about controllers, stages etc. Thank you

Comment: one question, what does mean the "object of it"? I must call constructor of second form before I run first?

Comment: I wrote object of it because you dont need to use Static Methods. Btw you named that class a controller and i didn't really get it but i think that was a class of yourself not of a FXML controller right?

Comment: xxxxxxcontroller is really  FXML controller.

Comment: Then get it the same way as the first one. It's simple. In the SysselManager2 class you just get both controllers. And then you pass controller1 into the method of controller2. The End

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the perfect case to use a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for your first class.
This way, you get a reference to the instance of your first class that can be used to invoke non-static methods from other classes.

your first class would look something like that:

```
public class ClassA {
    private static ClassA instance = null;
    private ClassA(){} //private constructor;

    public static getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) instance = new ClassA();
        return instance;
    }
    public void seznamDokumentu() {} //etc.
}
```

and in the second class:

```
private static void aktualizuj() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException {
ClassA.getInstance().seznamDokumentu();
}
```

Comment: This make new instance but i need work with existing instance right?
Becouse I created objects in old instance? When i use this solution I have my fxml objects (tableview etc.) null

Comment: No, this won't make a new instance usually (except something went terribly wrong and your old instance is lost).
Rather, you'd get a new instance, when you use getInstance() for the first time (creating your normal instance) and from then on, you'll get the same instance every time you use getInstance().

Comment: But the OP needs the instance created by the `FXMLLoader`. Besides which, a controller class is a completely inappropriate use of a singleton anyway; what if you need more than one instance of the node created by the FXML file? Each one would need its own controller.

Comment: Yeah, but this wasn't really clear from the question (at least for me).

Answer (score -1):

by default this problem is a very common for any kind of purposes I guess.

If I get you right, you simply want to call method from class1 in class2.
Respecting complexity there are several possible solutions:

Easiest, and probably best in your case is to create an instance of class1 in class2.

```
Class1 instance = new Class1();
```

Then you can easily access it's non-static methods by:

```
instance.seznamDokumentu();
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: But with this solution I lost old object. I have inicialized fxml object like tableview column etc.